# Mozilla Firefox not loading images from local machine

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

I am trying to run a simple html page with an image and div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .container {
       width: 240px;
       height: 280px;
       position: relative;
    }
 
  .tag {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0px;
 height: 220px;
 width: 202px;
    background-color: #4a8ab0;
 border-radius: 6px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
 opacity: 0.9;
    }
 
 .sideHeader {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 
 p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11.5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 }
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--​-->
<div class="container">
       <img src="D:/ata/images/cropped_box.jpg" style="height:210px;width:240px;">
    <div class="tag"><div class="sideHeader"><b>Did you know</b></div>
  <p>
   With HTML you can create your own Website.This tutorial teaches you everything about HTML.HTML is easy to learn - You will enjoy it.
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I could successfully run the code in Google chrome and Internet Explorer where the image and div is shown. While in mozilla firefox, the image is not displayed. It shows no error as well. I tried using an Image in internet. Which is showing fine. Why mozilla behaves different with local data? Is that a browser specific issue? I am using the version 66.0.2 (64-bit) version of firefox. How can I fix the same? I tried changing the backslashes to front slashes. but it doesn't work. please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution is quite simple. Rewrite the image tag as:

```
<img src="file://D:/ata/images/cropped_box.jpg" style="height:210px;width:240px;">
```